# What do negative coordinates mean with cv2.perspectiveTransform?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

What do negative coordinates mean when I apply the function:

```
    transformed_coordinates = cv2.perspectiveTransform(points, homography)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20perspectiveTransform(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20m)) ,mentions nothing about this. Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative coordinates are entirely normal.  That means that the projected points from 3D space to 2D image space are out of bounds or defined outside of the image boundaries.  It's not documented because it's implicit.

Now you are probably wondering *why* you're getting these.  I have no idea where `points` came from, but I suspect that you are visualizing some point cloud in 3D space and the transform maps visible points from the point cloud to where the camera is located.  Therefore, it's perfectly normal to have points that are outside the field of view of the camera be mapped to negative coordinates which tells you they simply cannot appear or be visualized when projected to image space.

Comment: I am trying to create a panorama and in doing that I am projecting points of image 1 onto image 2 and using this H matrix to find the perspectiveTransform

Comment: Then there are feature points that are not visible in the other view.